# como crear una grid en boostrap con 3 cuadros

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

hola me a dado por aprender bootstrap 4 y ahora se me ha presentado esta dificultad (diseño un blog) quiero ubicar un container con 3 cuadros uno grande que cubra la mitad y los otros dos mas pequeños uno encima del otro pero nose como se hace dejo una imagen ayuda un poco mas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el código que hasta ahora tengo pero el segundo row ubica mal los cuadros

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 b">
                    <h5>...</h5>
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 c"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 d"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Con que versión de bootstrap estas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que quieres hacer una grilla que aparentemente siempre tendrá el mismo layout, puedes agregar simplemente las clases respectivas a la columna de la derecha para que el contenedor "principal" de dicha columna ocupe el 100% del alto `h-100` y a los dos subcontenedores, les aplicar el 50% del alto a cada uno con la clase `h-50`.

```css
.b {
      background-color: red;
    }

    .c {
      background-color: blue;
    }

    .d {
      background-color: black;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 b">
                    <h5>...</h5>
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
                    <div class="row h-100">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 c h-50">..</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 d h-50">..</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez te sirva algo como esto:

```css
.row{
  
  height: 200px;
  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 bg-dark ">
        <h5>Titulo</h5>
        <p>Texto</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 bg-primary ">Cuadro uno</div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 bg-danger">Cuadro dos</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Solo la parte responsiva estaría pendiente.